# Mapping of a WordPress page to a custom URL without URL redirection

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am redesigning my website to a WordPress website, but the earlier websites links are present all over the internet. Like: http://www.doamin.com/some_folder/some_page.htm etc.

New website in WordPress will not have such URLs. And I do not want to redirect user to new WordPress URLs as of now because I fear of losing google ranking of existing URLs if URL path is changed by redirection.

So, is there any way to map new WordPress based URL to old URLs so that when user visits old URLs, user sees the new WordPress pages but the URL of that page remains the same as old URL.

Is there a plugin for it? or is there a file in WordPress in which I can write Like:

```
[Old URL 1]  [New_URL 1]
[Old URL 2]  [New_URL 2]
[Old URL 3]  [New_URL 3]
```

So that WordPress shows new page on old URL from reading this file but not redirects to new URL.

Answer (score -1):

You can use word press plugin in which there is .htm extension in end of each page / post slug which can maintain google ranking by keep same URL of new page.

[.html in url](https://wordpress.org/plugins/html-in-url/)

In above plugin you can keep .htm in end of each pahe / post slug by set permalink accordingly which is little custom from plugin guide line.

E.g. Permalink strucure:

```
/%postname%.htm
```